# Toggle function add column-break-before only working in safari

Tags: javascript, css

I have some li elements in a 2 column columncount design. I want to add the following function to the site: If you click on a div element (which is inside a li element), it should add a class with:

```
-webkit-column-break-before:always;
-moz-column-break-before:always;
background-color: fuchsia; /* only for demonstration */
```

With this function I can force the following elements to float onto the second column. I need this for printing.

Unfortunately this only works in Safari, not in Chrome nor Firefox (always on latest version).

Please click on the grey element in my fiddle to understand my description correctly:
https://jsfiddle.net/nickkkk/9nrtdg6q/3/

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should add jquery before you added your js file.

```
1. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
2. <script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Second, don´t forget the document.ready function.

Third, the classes you want to toggle has to be added separate in semicolons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.day').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled', 'day');
  });

})
```

Hope this helps ;-)